# Is there API in WP8.1 to control volume

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have looked through hundreds of pages, but haven't find an answer to question:

Is there a way to turn off volume via API call in new WP8.1

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know, but I am 99.9% sure there isn't one to do it globally as it would mess up user's settings. You should be able to control the volume of at least some audio sources that come from your app - such as a MediaElement or XAudio2 - these things have volume controls.

Comment: But I want to control global volume. I want to automate volume level, depending on time of day. I hope it's will be possible

Comment: The winrt apps are sandboxed so as not to interfere with user's choices and I doubt that API will be exposed any time soon in a similar vein as apps aren't able to pin themselves or do anything else that might adversely impact the operation of the device. No downvoting will change that.

Comment: There is an apps in market that can control volume. They use some kind of private APIs. My quesion were about public.

Comment: If apps can use private APIs - they can probably do mostly anything a desktop app could. Public apps in the store are sandboxed which means they can do whatever they are allowed in their zone, but not much that could affect the whole system.

Answer (score 0):

There is no third party available APIs to control the OS volume from third party applications for neither Silverlight nor Universal Apps.